# Silverlight displays solution name as title of page until application loads

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight 4 application and I cleverly name my apps by whatever color strikes me as appropriate to the project I am building. | It works for me. | My problem is that when I launch the application the solution/project name displays in the title/tab until the home page loads and then whatever I have set as my page title in my resx loads. It exhibits the same behavior on production as well as my development box, in-browser and out-of-browser.

I have poked around until I am crossed-eyed but cannot find a way to display a more appropriate title on initial load. This isn't a project killer by any means but an inconsistency that I find rather annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the title of the page in the Title tag of the aspx file in your Web project.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hate it when it is that simple...and kind of love it at the same time. :)